# How to identify possible chain pattern from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Edited

Looking for easy or optimized way of implementing below problem, seems with "networkx" we can achieve this quite easily (Thanks to BENY in comment section)

```
input_list  = [('A','B'),('D','C'),('C','B'),('E','D'),('I','J'),('L','K'),('J','K')] # path map

def get_chain_list(sp, d):
    global result
    result.append(sp)
    if sp in d : get_chain_list(d[sp], d)
    return tuple(result)

d = dict(input_list)
s1 = set(d.keys())
s2 = set(d.values())
sps = s1 - s2

master_chain = []
for sp in sps :
    result = []
    master_chain.append(get_chain_list(sp, d))

output_list = sorted(master_chain, key=len, reverse=True)

print(output_list)
[('E', 'D', 'C', 'B'), ('I', 'J', 'K'), ('A', 'B'), ('L', 'K')] # Chains in input list
```

Comment: I don't think you need machine learning/statistics for this, unless I'm misunderstanding what type of "chain pattern" you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a `networkx` problem

```
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(input_list)
l = [*nx.connected_components(G)]
Out[6]: [{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}, {'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

`output_list =  set(input_list)`

then form the required chain pattern using tuples like so:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

input_list  = [('A','B'),('D','C'),('C','B'),
    ('E','D'),('I','J'),('L','K'),('J','K')]

src=sorted({e for t in input_list for e in t})
ss=""
tgt=[]

for c in src:
    if ss+c in ascii_uppercase:
        ss+=c
    else:
        tgt.append(tuple(ss))
        ss=c
else:
    tgt.append(tuple(ss))

>>> tgt
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), ('I', 'J', 'K', 'L')]
```